# How to get the absolute coordinates of a view in Android by modifying the framework

Tags: view, scrollview, absolute, coordinate

I tried to get the absolute coordinates of a view in Android using the general methods such as getLocationOnScreen() or getLocationInWindow() or Rect. But these methods returned the wrong values like negative values or no exact numbers.

For example, the widgets of the second view have negative values after swiping and scrollviews as well(probably those values are calculated based on the first view of Scrollview). I used the layout called 'Draglayer' in Launcher3.

I should draw the picture on the right coordinates.